# For $S$ self adjoint, find a polynomial $q$ s.t. $q(S) = \text{arctan}(e^{S})$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, self-adjoint-operators

Let S be a self adjoint operator defined on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, with mutually distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_{1},...\lambda_{m}$, $m \leq n$. Then according to the spectral theorem one has:
$$S = \sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_{j} \pi_{j}$$
Where $\pi_{j}$ is the orthogonal projection on the eigenspace of $\lambda_{j}$. Find polynomials $p$ and $q$ such that: $p(S) = 0$ and $q(S) = \text{arctan}(e^{S})$!

I think that $p$ has to be the characteristic polynomial of $S$, so $p(t) = (t-\lambda_{1})\cdots(t-\lambda_{m})$ right? But what about $q$? Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: For $p$, any polynomial that is divisible by $\prod_{j=1}^{m}(t-\lambda_j)$ will work. For $q$, you need to find a polynomial such that $q(\lambda_j)=\arctan(e^{\lambda_j})$. There are many ways to realize such one, including the [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it now!